# Save dataframe to a schema/database.table (in HBase) using Phoenix (by Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, schema, apache-phoenix

I successfully save dataframe to HBase table (with no schema) using Phoenix with this code:

```
df_user.write
  .format("org.apache.phoenix.spark")
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .option("table", "table_name")
  .option("zkUrl", hbaseZkUrl)
  .save()
```

(More guide here: https://phoenix.apache.org/phoenix_spark.html)

But **my table is contained in a schema/database** (format: `schema_name.table_name`). So, we do not find any solution to save in this table.

I have tried the below code but failed:

```
df_user.write
  .format("org.apache.phoenix.spark")
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .option("table", "schema_name.table_name")
  .option("zkUrl", hbaseZkUrl)
  .save()
```

```
df_user.write
  .format("org.apache.phoenix.spark")
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .schema("schema_name")
  .option("table", "table_name")
  .option("zkUrl", hbaseZkUrl)
  .save()
```

Does anyone have a solution for my problem? Many thanks!